# How do I make a sprite change directions when tapped?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skaction

When first touched, my player starts moving up the y axis and I have it set up like so:

```
 override func touchesBegan(...) {
if isMovingup == true  {
        let up = SKAction.moveByX(0, y: 900, duration: 9)
         player.runAction(up)
    }
    else {
        let down = SKAction.moveByX(0, y: -900, duration: 9)
        player.runAction(down)
 }
    isMovingup = !isMovingup
    }
```

However, when the node is tapped a second time, Id like it to move down the y axis but as of now, it just does nothing. Will post more code if necessary.

Comment: looking at this again,  perhaps the code you posted needs to be retyped, or more elaborated on.  you have an extra curly brace above the isMovingup change,  was this intentional, or a mistype? As of right now, your code should not even be compiling, which makes me wonder if your touchBegan function is set up correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to stop the previous action with `player.removeAllActions()`  otherwise your actions will keep stacking.

```
override func touchesBegan(...) {
    player.removeAllActions() //<-- Touching always causes the player to change direction, so lets cancel out the previous action before assigning a new one
    if isMovingup == true  {
        let up = SKAction.moveByX(0, y: 900, duration: 9)
        player.runAction(up)
    }
    else {
        let down = SKAction.moveByX(0, y: -900, duration: 9)
        player.runAction(down)
    }
    isMovingup = !isMovingup
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on this please?

Comment: This works perfectly. Thank you so much! Sorry for the original typo.

Comment: It is fine,  I assumed it was a typo,  but after the answers from others, I had to comment to make sure we corrected the question in some way

Comment: As a note,  the only time you should put the removeAllActions inside of the if statement is if there is a condition where touching would not cause the player to change direction.  The less redundant code means the less mistakes that can happen.

Answer (score 2):

It looks as if your boolean flip is outside the scope of the function. Try moving the line `isMovingup = !isMovingup` to inside the last curly brace.

```
override func touchesBegan(...) {
    if isMovingup {
        let up = SKAction.moveByX(0, y: 900, duration: 9)
        player.runAction(up)
    }
    else {
        let down = SKAction.moveByX(0, y: -900, duration: 9)
        player.runAction(down)
    }
    isMovingup = !isMovingup
}
```

Comment: Whoops, that was a typo. It is inside that last curly brace but not doing what Id hoped.

Comment: I see. Possibly the answer from KnightOfDragon solves your problem.

Comment: Okay, where in the conditional would I put that?

Comment: Possibly inside each if / else clause, prior to adding an `up` or `down` action to player object.

Comment: Can you give me an example in code? Sorry, its early.

Comment: If you need specifications to Knight0fDragons answer, it's probably better to kindly ask him to edit his answer to include such an example.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be that the code piece

```
isMovingup = !isMovingup
```

Is defined outside of the function, so it is not being run. Move it inside the function after the else statement so it will be run everytime you call the function

```
override func touchesBegan(...) {
    if isMovingup == true  {
        let up = SKAction.moveByX(0, y: 900, duration: 9)
        player.runAction(up)
    }
    else {
        let down = SKAction.moveByX(0, y: -900, duration: 9)
        player.runAction(down)
   }
   isMovingup = !isMovingup
}
```